# How do you differentiate between zero and not-initialised in C?

Tags: c, pointers, nullpointerexception, null

How do you check if a value is zero or has not been given?

```
int points[3];
points[0]=1;
points[1]=0;

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(points)/sizeof(*points);i++){

    if(points[i]&&points>0){printf("Value is %d \n",points[i]);}
    else if(!points[i]){printf("Value is zero \n");}
    else{printf("Not set/provided\n");} // catching points[2]
}
```

Here, how do you differentiate between `points[1]` and `points[2]`?

Comment: You keep track of the highest assigned index in another variable.

Comment: By default memory will not be initialized to anything, so it will be whatever the memory was before the variable was assigned that memory location (so essentially undetermined).  NULL is typically defined as zero, so you can't even make a distinction there.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you're absolutely tight, it was bad terminology. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How do you differentiate between zero and not-set" and "how do you differentiate between points[1] and points[2]" implies a misunderstanding.  `points[2]` in this case is not initialized nor assigned.  It is not specified to be any legitimate value.

`if(points[i] ...` is UB when `i==2`.

Assign `points[2]` before reading it.

---

> How do you differentiate between zero and not-initialised in C?

Code does so by keeping track of elements initialized or assigned prior.  In this case, only `points[0], points[1]` has been assigned.  Code does not attempt to differentiate by reading `points[i]`.

A common idiom is to first zero fill the entire object:

```
int points[3] = { 0 };
```

Comment: the idiom is quite handy!

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way without initialization.
In some cases such as debug mode in vs, they will be initialized with zero, but in generally, c or c++ engine will set random values to non-initialized variables.

You have to do as follows:

```
int points[3] = {1, 0, -1};

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (points[i] > 0) printf("value: %d", points[i]);
    else if (points[i] == 0) printf("value is zero");
    else printf("value is not setted.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not have any feature to find uninitialized value. If the uninitialized variable is static or global, its value will be always 0, else it could be anything in the range of the type of variable. What you can do is assign a sentinel value as an indicator.

For example, if you are certain that the value of the variable will always be positive then you can assign a negative number to keep track, if the variable is ever changed or not